# RSA exponent size

Tags: encryption, rsa, biginteger

I am learning about the RSA algorithm. I perform the algorithm on very small prime numbers and use online Big Integer calculators to perform the encryption and decryption and everything works just fine.

My question is about the size of the exponent we create and when it comes to bigger numbers, it seems infeasible to calculate.

For example, the algorithm starts with picking two prime numbers p and q. You compute n=pxq and then the totient of n. Next you pick a number 'e' such that 1

Then to perform an encryption you take say like the ASCII character 'A' which is 65 and you raise it to the power of e. (65^e)

The online big integer calculator started getting very slow and sluggish (over a minute to calculate) when e was bigger than about 100,000 (6 digits)

My question is then, for the working RSA algorithm, what size (number of digits) number does that algorithm pick?

One thought I had was it was possible the online calculator that I was using was not using the best method for exponents? This is the calculator I am using: http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm

Comment: A modulus of 2048 bit is 617 decimal places long. An exponent is usually chosen as 3 or 65537

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to software development and all can be answered by the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

Comment: If you're asking about the performance impact, this is done with special modular exponentiation algorithms such as square and muliply

Comment: It looks from its source like that JS bigint calculator is trying to use a more-or-less reasonable modular exponentiation approach (square-and-multiply), so perhaps much of the explanation here is just that the carefully optimized bigint implementations used production RSA implementations are just faster at the multiplications and so on than that JavaScript is. (Note that public exponents [usually aren't higher than 65537](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537) but private exponents of course can be huge.)

Comment: @ArtjomB. So in general the exponent is always 3 or 65537? That is a very useful answer. I wanted to make sure that it was never going to be a very extremely large number.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The WIKI article never suggests that. It simply says select a number 'e' bigger than 1 and less than the totient(n).

Comment: @Matthew: You're missing the larger point. Even if the encrypt exponent is *typically* small, the decrypt exponent is large, about the size of the modulus. You are performing the exponentiation step incorrectly. Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) wikipedia article to understand the algorithms that are used in many public key crypto protocols including RSA.

Comment: The idea is that **moduluar exponentiation** is much faster than exponentiation followed by a modulus calculation. The calculator that you point out doesn't contain any input field for the modulus. So it first has to calculate a gargantuan number which will take oodles of time ("You know, I've always liked that word... 'gargantuan'... so rarely have an opportunity to use it in a sentence.")

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `M` is the modulus. So YES, you could first perform `intermediate = 65^e`, and finally compute `intermediate mod M`. And of course, `intermediate` would be a very very very very big integer (if `e` equals 65537, the decimal representation of `intermediate` contains 118813 digits!).

BUT, **thanks to a very basic modular arithmetic theorem**,

```
(65^e) mod M = ((((65 mod M) * 65) mod M) * 65) mod M [...] (e times)
```

(*the theorem states that in a quotient ring, the n-th power of the class of an element is the class of the n-th power of the element*)

As you can see, this does not need any very big integer library, since after each arithmetic product, you use `mod M` that returns an integer between `0` and `M-1`. So, you only have to compute arithmetic products of integers less than M.

As an example, here is a simple shell script (bash) that computes 65^65537 mod 991*997. **As you can see, no need to get a big number library:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# set RSA parameters
m=65           # message to encode
M=$((991*997)) # modulus (both 991 and 997 are prime numbers)
e=65537        # public exponent (coprime with 990*996, thus compliant with RSA algorithm)

# compute (m^e) mod M
ret=1
for i in {1..$e}
do
  ret=$(((ret*m)%M))
done

# display the result
echo $ret
```

It immediately returns `784933`, thus `65^65537 mod 991*997 = 784933`

The biggest integer computed with your method of calculus has 118813 digits, but the biggest integer handled with this shell script only has 12 or less digits (`(M-1)^2` is made of 12 digits).

**According to these explanations, we can now answer your question:**

> My question is then, for the working RSA algorithm, what size (number of digits) number does that algorithm pick?

With the above explanations, you can see that the maximum number of digits in the decimal representation of integers you have to manipulate is `1+log10((M-1)^2)`, because you will, at most, compute a product of two integers between `0` and `M-1`.

Note that `1+log10((M-1)^2) = 1+2.log10(M-1) < 2+2.log10(M) = 2.(1+log10(M))`. Also note that `1+log10(M)` is the number of digits of M.

Therefore, as a conclusion, this proves that **the number of digits your library has to handle correctly is twice the number of digits of the modulus** (if you are computing the exponentiation using integer multiplications the way explained here).

Comment: Are you sure about that last sentence? Can't you just strip off digits once they get over the bit size of N, the modulus?

Comment: What do you mean by "strip off" ? For instance, with a modulus of 1 digit (number 2*3=6), if you need to compute `4*5 mod 6`, that equals to `20 mod 6`, that finally equals to 2, how do you "strip off" bits to only work with 1 digit numbers ?

Comment: Well, you could perform modular multiplication by implementing it using modular addition. In that case you would only need one additional digit instead of N additional digits, right?

Comment: Yes, if you avoid using your library to compute products, but only use additions, you can do N additions to compute the value of the product by N, and then you are right, you will only need one additional digit. The trade-off is that big integer libraries are optimized to compute products, so I think it will be really slower to make N additions compared to one product, if N is big. But if you have not the choice because you want to save digits, this is a way to do it.

Comment: Anyway, just playing with you, I think most RSA implementations do actually use a buffer twice the key size :P Using modular addition is way to slow. But I asked because you were giving an example using modular multiplication, which *could* be implemented using modular addition.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean => I've edited the answer and added *if you are computing the exponentiation using integer multiplications the way explained here* at the end of the last sentence. Thanks.